# PSI/SI Pat Packet Output

Tags: vb.net

I am developing PSI SI software. I am new to this technology. By reading some material, I have made some of the PSI packets and sending through UDP.

I am converting it into Hexadecimal and sending them throough UDP.

I am using wireshark and TS Reader to check whether packets are properly created. In wireshark it shows the table name in info column i.e. PAT, BAT etc.

But in TS reader nothing comes up. What I am missing? I have tried many ways but no way it comes in TSReader.

Is there any special that need to be used? Is there any other part that I need to work before sending the packets and to make them view in TS Reader?

Packet:

```
47 60 00 10 00 00 F0 35 00 01 e3 00 01 00 00 00 10 01 01 01 b1 01 02 01 b2 01 03 01 b3 01 04 01 b4 01 06 1f ff 01 07 01 b7 01 0a 01 ba 01 0b 01 bb 01 18 10 30 01 1a 10 31 ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
```

Packet Output in wireshark

[image]

No Output in TSReader:

[image]